# Javascript constructors - when do errors occur?

Tags: javascript, constructor

Нello! In javascript just about any value can successfully have its `constructor` retrieved:

```
console.log((33).constructor); // Number
console.log((false).constructor); // Boolean
console.log(('hello').constructor); // String
console.log(({}).constructor); // Object
console.log(([]).constructor); // Array
console.log((v => v).constructor); // Function
```

I also know that you can make a class whose instances will not have a `constructor` property:

```
let O = function(){};
O.prototype = Object.create(null);
console.log((new O()).constructor)); // undefined
```

What interests me here is values which cause errors when an attempt is made to retrieve their constructors. I'm only aware of two such values:

```
console.log((null).constructor); // TypeError!
console.log((undefined).constructor); // TypeError!
```

My question is: **Are `null` and `undefined` the only two possible values with such behaviour?**

Comment: Note that numbers, bools, strings etc. are *boxed* when you try to call their methods or access their properties. These boxing objects have a constructor. `null` and `undefined`, however, don't have such boxed equivalents, and therefore no constructor.

Comment: Nope, here is another one: `({ get constructor ( ) { throw new TypeError; } }).constructor`

Comment: Also, there is nothing special about `constructor` as far as `null` and `undefined` are concerned. Accessing any property of `null` or `undefined` gives the same error.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol do you have a link related to this concept of "boxing"? It's difficult to google for. It sounds like whether a value is boxed determines if property access results in `undefined` or `TypeError`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: Are null and undefined the only two possible values with such behaviour?

By default, yes, because if a property doesn't exist on an object or any of its prototypes, you get the value `undefined`. The reason `null` and `undefined` throw is you can't try to get properties from them. They're the only things that behave that way when you try to get properties from them.

However, any object can be *made* to throw an error when you get the `constructor` property, either directly:

```js
const o = {
  get constructor() {
    throw new Error("Don't do that!");
  }
};
console.log(o.constructor);
```

or using a Proxy where a trap prevents it:

```js
const o = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, propName, receiver) {
    if (propName === "constructor") {
      throw new Error("Don't do that!");
    }
    return Reflect.get(target, propName, receiver);
  }
});
console.log(o.constructor);
```